# Rational map on $\mathbb P^1$ and its fibers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, fibration

Consider a non-singular complex projective surface $S$ and a rational map $\psi:S\longrightarrow \mathbb P^1$; moreover suppose that $\psi$ is not defined on $\Delta=\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}\subset S$. Now I have the following question:

> Let $y\in\mathbb P^1$ be a closed point and consider the fiber $\psi^{-1}(y)$. Is it true that $\psi^{-1}(y)\cup\Delta$ is the closure in $S$ of $\psi^{-1}(y)$? (Certainly it is a closed subset containing $\psi^{-1}(y)$).

Practically in my mind I imagine a fiber of $\psi$ as a curve on $S$ minus $m=|\Delta|$ points. Can $\psi^{-1}(x)$ be a curve of $S$ minus $m-k$ points (with $k=1,\ldots,m$)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there such a $\psi$ being defined everywhere besides finitely many points? By Hartogs there should be an unique extension to all of $S$, or what am I missing here?

Comment: Hartshorne, Lemma V.5.1, says that the fundamental points of  a rational map form a closed subset of codimension $2$. So in the case of complex projective surfaces we get a only finite number of fundamental points.

Comment: Oh, stupid stupid me... I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why would the closure include all the points of nondefinition?

Comment: Ok the question is the following: In general a fiber $\psi^{-1}(y)$ is closed in $S\setminus\Delta$ but not closed in $S$. In which way can you obtain its closure?  

By adding only some points of nondefinition?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: the point, is that if the closure of _some_ fibre didn't contain a point of nondefinition, then that point would be contained in the closure of precisely _one_ fibre. (See my answer for details.) But then the map could be defined there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Let me give an answer here, and see if you are happy with it; I will give extra details if necessary.

Fix two points in $\mathbf P^1$, which we'll call $0$ and $\infty$. Let $D_0$ and $D_\infty$ be the closures in $S$ of the fibres over these points. So $D_0$ and $D_\infty$ are divisors on $S$. There is a rational function on $\mathbf P^1$ whose divisor is $(0)-(\infty)$; pulling this rational function back via $\psi$, we get a rational function on $S$ whose divisor is $D_0-D_\infty$. (It might seem like we only proved this on the locus of definition of $\psi$, but since $S$ is smooth this extends to all of $S$.)

So $D_0$ and $D_\infty$ are linearly equivalent divisors on $S$. In the language of line bundles, there is a line bundle $L$ with two global sections $s_0, s_\infty$ whose zero loci are precisely the two divisors. Now consider sections of $L$ of the form $\lambda s_0 + \mu s_\infty$: the zero loci of these sections are exactly the closures of the fibres of $\psi$! Explicitly, $D_{[\lambda:\mu]} = \{ \lambda s_0 + \mu s_\infty =0\}$ is the closure of the fibre over the point $[\lambda : \mu] \in \mathbf P^1$, where $[1 : 0] = 0$ and $[0:1]=\infty$. (If this seems sketchy: note that each $D_{[\lambda:\mu]}$ is a subvariety of $S$ of pure codimension 1, and when we remove finitely many points from it we get the fibre over $[\lambda:\mu]$. )

Now for any given point $p \in S$, the condition $\{ \lambda s_0(p) + \mu s_\infty(p) =0\}$ is a homogeneous linear condition on $\lambda$ and $\mu$, and it is satisfied precisely when $p \in D_{[\lambda:\mu]}$. So there are 3 possibilities:

1. Only solution is $\lambda=\mu=0$, so that $p$ is not in the closure of any fibre. But this case is impossible: one equation in two variables must have at least one non-trivial solution.
2. 1-dimensional space of solutions. Then there is a unique $[\lambda: \mu] \in \mathbf P^1$ such that $p \in D_{[\lambda:\mu]}$. In this case the map $\psi$ is well-defined at $p$, and sends it to $[\lambda: \mu]$. (If this seems a bit sketchy: trivialise $L$ near $p$ and use this to write $s_0$ and $s_\infty$ as regular functions near $p$. Then check that the formula $x \mapsto [s_0(x):s_1(x)]$ extends $\psi$ over $p$.)
3. 2-dimensional space of solutions. In this case $p \in D_{[\lambda:\mu]}$ for all $[\lambda: \mu] \in \mathbf P^1$ — in other words, $p$ is in the closure of every fibre. By the previous cases, this is what must happen if $\psi$ is not defined at $p$.

Comment: A slicker approach would be to blow up $S$ to resolve the indeterminacy, and show that each exceptional curve on the blowup maps onto $\mathbf P^1$. I wanted to give the most down-to-earth proof I could.

Comment: Your answer is clear, but I'm intrested to your last comment. Can you give me some extra details about the "second method" to prove the claim? Why each exceptional curve maps onto $\mathbb P^1$? And why this implies that claim?

Comment: Ok a $(-1)$-curve $E$ can't be mapped to a point of $\mathbb P^1$ since this implies that $E^2=0$... But what about the second question?

Comment: @Dubious: I should have been a little more precise in my comment. It is not true in general that _each_ exceptional curve maps onto $\mathbf P^1$: some of them might map to points. (This does not imply $E^2=0$.) But _at least one_ exceptional curve over each point of indeterminacy must map onto $\mathbf P^1$.

Comment: This implies the claim, because then each fibre $F$ of the resolved map intersects the exceptional divisor over each indeterminacy point. This would not happen if one of the indeterminacy points was not in the closure of $F$.

Comment: I don't understand only the followiing point:  "But at least one exceptional curve over each point of indeterminacy must map onto $\mathbb P^1$"

Comment: (This will be my last comment.) If not, then all those curves would map to the same point of $\mathbf P^1$, and then the original map $\psi$ would be well-defined at the indeterminacy point.